# Lagrangian invariance under Galilean transform and conservation law of linear momentum

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, galilean-relativity

I'm currently taking a course of analytical mechanics. We've learned about the invariance of the Lagrangian under change of coordinates, and showed that we get the same Lagrangian for free particle under Galilean transform.
In another lesson, we've talked about conservation laws and that if the Lagrangian is translation invariant then there's conservation of linear momentum.
I don't understand how can it be that we've showed that the Lagrangian is always translation invariant on one hand, but on the other hand, we know that linear momentum almost never is conserved which supposedly contradicts the conservation law of linear momentum. what am I missing?

The form of the lagrangian:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Well, if you claim that the conservation law doesn't hold, then the corresponding symmetry must be absent to begin with. E.g. a potential term $U(x)$ could destroy translation symmetry $x\to x +a$, and hence momentum conservation.

Comment: What is the form of the Lagrangian you've been presented with?

Comment: *we know that linear momentum almost never is conserved* Why do you say that?

Comment: @G.Smith what I meant was, in real life when two objects collide, there will be a loss of energy

Comment: @G.Smith Loss of kinetic energy does not imply momentum will not be conserved. Momentum will always be conserved in a two body collision (unless there is another body or a field which can take some of the momentum - even then, the total momentum will be conserved). Suppose two identical bodies with opposite velocities (hence, momoentums are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction) collide and stick together. The whole kinetic energy is lost, but the momentum is conserved.

Comment: yes, you are right. but there are a-lot of cases where external forces are applied on the system I choose. I still can't understand, if linear momentum isn't always conserved, what's the wrong with what I wrote? how can I explain that the Lagrangian is always translation invariant because of gauge freedom (as with Galilean transformation) but in contrast to the fact that the linear momentum should be conserved by conservation laws, it's not always the case?